# get client id of image control inside repeater inside gridview

Tags: javascript

How do I get client id of image control

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" OnRowDataBound="GetItems" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" Font-Names="tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="154px" Width="929px">
    <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="pic">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="pictures" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate> 
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" height="120" width="90"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' onclick="DisplayNewImageInWidnow();" />  
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I use this code but it doesn't work

```
function DisplayNewImageInWidnow()
{
    var img = document.getElementById('<%=gv.FindControl("pictures").FindControl("Image1").ClientID %>').src
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OnClientClick="return DisplayNewImageInWidnow();"
```

or prevent server side from running

```
OnClientClick="DisplayNewImageInWidnow();return false;"
```

then

```
function DisplayNewImageInWidnow(obj)
{
    var imgId = obj.id;
}
```

Comment: hi how to pass obj to function?

Comment: `"DisplayNewImageInWidnow(this);` sorry that was a really quickly formulated answer.